# how to use c++ code in flutter (android) application?

Tags: android, python, c++, dart, flutter

I am developing an application in Flutter (for Android) whose core is based on a library developed only in C++ and python. Therefore, I would like to know how I can use this library in my dart code (either the C++ version or the Python version).

Comment: can you give some sample code (both Dart and  C++), otherwise @Xavier answer seem to be the one.

Comment: Try this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8JD8hHkBMc) by Richard Heap, it helped me quiet a lot. He explains with an example how to interact between the Dart code of your Flutter app, and the C++ library you're using, all through ```dart:ffi```. I'd also recommend checking out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62351258/debug-c-code-from-dart-package-using-dartffi) for a way to debug the C++ code while running it through a Flutter app.

Answer (score 14):

## Additional information (2021-05-05)

From @FacundoFarall comment to the original question:

> Try this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8JD8hHkBMc) by Richard Heap, it helped me quiet a lot. He explains with an example how to interact between the Dart code of your Flutter app, and the C++ library you're using, all through dart:ffi. I'd also recommend checking out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62351258/debug-c-code-from-dart-package-using-dartffi) for a way to debug the C++ code while running it through a Flutter app.

## Update (2019-09-10)

Today has been [released Dart 2.5](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-5-super-charged-development-328822024970) (and Flutter 1.9). One of the additions to Dart 2.5 is "the dart:ffi foreign function interface for calling C code directly from Dart." I still haven't checked it, but it should provide a more direct path to interface with C (and C++) code.

See also the [announcement video](https://youtu.be/wzNd3yyLcaU?t=100) (confirms both old and new methods).

## Old answer (still valid)

I would take a look at Platform Channels, which are a way to communicate Flutter code to platform native code (e.g. Java/Kotlin on Android, Objective C/Swift in iOS). From there, you can use your C++ library using the regular NDK mechanisms.

You can see an introduction to [Flutter Platform Channels](https://medium.com/flutter-io/flutter-platform-channels-ce7f540a104e) and [Getting Started with the NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides).

Maybe there's a more direct route, but that's the one I know could work.

Comment: i checked first answer and it's ok with dart compiler but i could not use it in flutter, i raised a question for it  https://stackoverflow.com/q/57900637/2719243

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer with time :)