# Debug C++ code from Dart package using dart::ffi

Tags: c++, flutter, debugging, dart, dart-ffi

I am developing a package in C++ to be used in a Flutter app (and therefore in Dart), using [dart::ffi](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/c-interop) and I was wondering if there was a better way to debug (step by step, variable watch, that sort of things) the C++ code, other than logging messages. I've tried both in Android Studio and VS Code, with no success.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019

Comment: How would you suggest I do it? As far as I know, I can't run the Flutter app in Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Why can't you run it?

Comment: According to [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor?tab=vscode), the IDEs that you can use to debug are Android Studio, IntelliJ, VS Code and Emacs. Have you tried running a Flutter app in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Android Studio (or VS Code) doesn't support native (C/C++) code debugging while in Flutter mode (yet). However, there is a workaround! In the project tree, right-click the 'android' folder and select Flutter -> Open Android module in Android Studio. The project will switch to Android development mode where c/c++ debugging is fully supported. Now just search for the 'cpp' folder, set breakpoints in any of the files there and run the app (while still in the Android development mode of course)!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to debug some c code in VS Code using the follow configuration in launch.json, for a linux desktop app:

```
    {
        "name": "Debug Native",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/linux/x64/debug/bundle/app",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build/linux/x64/debug/bundle",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
```

Just modify the `app` in program according to the name of your app. Then in the debug tab you will be able to launch this configuration:

[image: launch Debug]

This configuration just launches the built executable. If you want it to build everytime before launching you need to add a `preLaunchTask`.